# What is the meaning of "every thing is a widget in Flutter"

Tags: flutter

If everything is a widget, why do we have to cast/specify Widget in return, i.e. see below.

example 1:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

What else build can return that will cause error?

example 2:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('We move under cover and we move as one'),
    Text('Through the night,
```

If everything is a widget then why do I have to specify `<Widget>` before square brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't literally mean that "everything is a widget",

literally it means "every thing drawn on a screen is a widget"

and this of course does not mean that there are no types in flutter(more precisely dart) other than `Widget` type

For example you can return a type `int` or `null` or `String` from `build`, which will crash your app

Comment: I'm just confused with the statement everything is a widget, it is the responsibility of the programmer to return a ui widget on build and let the system crash with an error, and let the programmer correct the error, no difference than creating a function specifying a return type and the programmer not returning the correct type so either the app will crash (runtime error) or get caught before running (I don't know the error term). Thank you for your answer, it's just another confusing syntax for a beginner.